# How does the sgolay function work in Matlab R2013a?

Tags: matlab, filtering, smoothing, derivative

I have a question about the [`sgolay`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sgolay.html) function in Matlab R2013a. My database has 165 spectra with 2884 variables and I would like to take the first and second derivatives of them. How might I define the inputs `K` and `F` to `sgolay`?

Below is an example:

`sgolay` is used to smooth a noisy sinusoid and compare the resulting first and second derivatives to the first and second derivatives computed using `diff`. Notice how using `diff` amplifies the noise and generates useless results.

```
K = 4;                 % Order of polynomial fit
F = 21;                % Window length
[b,g] = sgolay(K,F);   % Calculate S-G coefficients

dx = .2;
xLim = 200;
x = 0:dx:xLim-1;

y = 5*sin(0.4*pi*x)+randn(size(x));  % Sinusoid with noise

HalfWin  = ((F+1)/2) -1;
for n = (F+1)/2:996-(F+1)/2,
  % Zero-th derivative (smoothing only)
  SG0(n) =   dot(g(:,1), y(n - HalfWin: n + HalfWin));

  % 1st differential
  SG1(n) =   dot(g(:,2), y(n - HalfWin: n + HalfWin));

  % 2nd differential
  SG2(n) = 2*dot(g(:,3)', y(n - HalfWin: n + HalfWin))';
end

SG1 = SG1/dx;         % Turn differential into derivative
SG2 = SG2/(dx*dx);    % and into 2nd derivative

% Scale the "diff" results
DiffD1 = (diff(y(1:length(SG0)+1)))/ dx;    
DiffD2 = (diff(diff(y(1:length(SG0)+2)))) / (dx*dx);

subplot(3,1,1);
plot([y(1:length(SG0))', SG0'])
legend('Noisy Sinusoid','S-G Smoothed sinusoid')

subplot(3, 1, 2);
plot([DiffD1',SG1'])
legend('Diff-generated 1st-derivative', 'S-G Smoothed 1st-derivative')

subplot(3, 1, 3);
plot([DiffD2',SG2'])
legend('Diff-generated 2nd-derivative', 'S-G Smoothed 2nd-derivative')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking derivatives in an inherently noisy process. Thus, if you already have some noise in your data, indeed, it will be magnified as you take higher order derivatives. [Savitzky-Golay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky-Golay_filter) is a very useful way of combining smoothing and differentiation into one operation. It's a general method and it computes derivatives to an arbitrary order. There are trade-offs, though. Other special methods exist for data with a certain structure.

In terms of your application, I don't have any concrete answers. Much depends on the nature of the data (sampling rate, noise ratio, etc.). If you use too much smoothing, you'll smear your data or produce aliasing. Same thing if you over-fit the data by using high order polynomial coefficients, `K`. In your demo code you should also plot the analytical derivatives of the `sin` function. Then play with different amounts of input noise and smoothing filters. Such a tool with known exact answers may be helpful if you can approximate aspects of your real data. In practice, I try to use as little smoothing as possible in order to produce derivatives that aren't too noisy. Often this means a third-order polynomial (`K = 3`) and a window size, `F`, as small as possible.

So yes, many suggest that you [use your eyes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/322473) to tune these parameters. However, there has also been some very recent research on choosing the coefficients automatically: *[On the Selection of Optimum Savitzky-Golay Filters](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2012.2225055)* (2013). There are also alternatives to Savitzky-Golay, e.g., [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.5402/2011/164564) based on [regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization), but you may need to implement them yourself in Matlab.

By the way, a while back I wrote a little replacement for `sgolay`. Like you, I only needed the second output, the differentiation filters, `G`, so that's all it calculates. This function is also faster (by about 2–4 times):

```
function G=sgolayfilt(k,f)
%SGOLAYFILT  Savitzky-Golay differentiation filters
s = vander(0.5*(1-f):0.5*(f-1));
S = s(:,f:-1:f-k);
[~,R] = qr(S,0);
G = S/R/R';
```

A full version of this function with input validation is [available on my GitHub](https://github.com/horchler/sgolayfilt).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and indication of article hockler, however, still have a doubt as part of the derivation that your proposed. I'm not close this part of programming, you could explain to me what this means and how each formula get my 165 pre-processed spectra (First and second derivative). Excuse the ignorance and also my writing, can not write in English law.

Comment: Thanks for the help horchler, problem solved. I was needed to study a little more about sgolay. Sorry anything.